# After migrating user from one AD to another AD, the user can no longer access WSS

Tags: active-directory, wss, active-directory-import

We have migrated users from one AD domain to another AD domain in SharePoint 2007. But after migration, the users can no longer access windows SharePoint services e.g, permissions and roles etc.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [stsadm -o migrateuser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141(v=office.12).aspx) to migrate a SharePoint user account in to a new login name. Further details can be found [here](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=75).

Comment: As we already have migrated all the users accounts from old AD domain to new AD domain. As i understand from your answer, you mean, we need to migrate all of our user accounts again from old AD domain to new AD domain by using stsadm -o migrateuser ? and in this way, all the permissions and roles associated with user accounts will be  migrated as well. Am i correct in my understanding ?

Comment: stsadm -o migrateuser simply replaces the associated AD account behind the SharePoint user, permissions, roles (SP group memberships), User field values (like Created by, Edited by, etc.) will reference the same SP User. You can interpret it so that the SP user have been migrated to the new AD account.

Comment: Just one more question: We need to migrate the Groups as well to new AD account. from your link i see that there is now way to migrate groups. Any idea to to fix this?

Comment: You should use stsadm -o migrategroup in this case (useful links: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2010/09/28/moss-running-stsadm-o-migrategroup-command-keeps-the-old-group-name-and-does-not-replace-with-the-new-name.aspx , http://www.flexecom.com/manipulate-sharepoint-permissions-after-migration/)

Comment: Thanks pholpar! One more question. By using stsadm -o migrateuser we can migrate single user one by one. In our case we have 1000+ users. how i can migrate all the users all at once. is there any way to do this. Because migrating 1000+ users one by one is a tiresome job?

Comment: Create a batch file that includes all the users, and start it in the background.
I would prepare the file by copying the former and new user names in two columns in Excel (or would use a single column if the names have the same pattern, but the domain name is the difference), and let the command be computed via an Excel formula in another column.
So can you migrate all the users at once, and you can work on other tasks in the meantime. If you had a newer SP version (2010 or 2013) it would be easier to automate the process via the Move-SPUser PowerShell CmdLet, but in 2007 it is not available.

Comment: Hi pholpar, Thanks for the suggestion. But still i did not got how i do this? after getting all the users in excel or csv file programatically, how i run the stsadm -o migrate user command? because i need to specify a single user in this command. please explain in detail how i proceed as i am pretty new to sharePoint. It can be a great help to me

Comment: Assume you have the same user names in old domain (domanOld) and new domain (domainNew). You insert the user login names (without domain!) in Excel in column A. Then in column B you can set a formula like this one: ="stsadm -migrateuser -oldlogin domainOld\" & $A1 & " -newlogin domainNew\" & $A1  .
If you copy the values from column B, you already have the commands prepared for your batch including a single stsadm -migrateuser command for each of the users.