# SharePoint 2010: Update Migrated Users Domain attribute after domain change

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server

We are planning to move a content database to another SharePoint farm in another domain and I anticipate that users might not be able to access the site in the new domain because of the change in the domain for example: old domain is FH\ and new domain is pk.

Will this be the case and if so:

- Is there a script stsadm and/or PowerShell to update the domain attribute of all users in SharePoint?
- I know of Move-SPUser, but that only applies to users individually, is there a script that can apply to all users?

  - For example, I want to change all user from fg\ domain to rw\ domain

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, if you extract the all user in the cvs then you can run the migrate user command against that CSV file.

[here is the script which required a CSV file.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Migrate-user-accounts-in-d9b854a1)

```
# Required parameters. 
param (  
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  
    [string]$InputCSVFile = "", 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  
    [string]$WebAppUrl = "" 
    )  

# Add Microsoft SharePoint PowerShell pssnapin. 
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

# Import all current and new user accounts. 
Import-Csv $InputCSVFile -Delimiter ","  |  

%{ 
    Try 
        { 
        # Get and create a user object by current user account. 
        Write-Host "Getting current user object by " -NoNewline 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $_.CurrentUser"..." 
        $user = Get-SPUser -web $WebAppUrl -Identity $_.CurrentUser -ErrorAction Stop 

        # Create new alias by new user account. 
        Write-Host "Creating new alias by " -NoNewline 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $_.NewUser "..." 
        Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias $_.NewUser -IgnoreSID -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "The new alias has been created." 
        } 
    Catch [Exception] 
        { 
        # Return error message. 
        return $_.exception 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for response.

In search of a simpler solution I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121206/migrating-user-accounts-from-one-ad-domain-to-another-ad-domain-using-powershell) solution. Please could you confirm if the below solution can be used

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sp2007")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local

$web.SiteUsers | ? {
  $_.LoginName -like 'domainold\*' 
} | % {
  $oldLogin = $_.LoginName
  $newLogin = $_.LoginName.ToLower().Replace('domainold\', 'domainnew\')
  $farm.MigrateUserAccount($oldLogin, $newLogin, $false) 
}`
```